# Add same new columns to all existing migration tables at once

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Let's say I have 30 migration tables. Now I want to add 2 new columns to all existing migrations table.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('organogram_id')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id')->nullable();

//foreign
$table->foreign('organogram_id')->references('id')->on('organograms')->onUpdate('cascade')- 
>onDelete('restrict');
$table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')->onUpdate('cascade')- 
>onDelete('restrict');
```

In Laravel we can add new columns to a table.Is there any way to add same columns to multiple tables?
should I iterate through all migrations and the new columns or is there any other way?

Comment: You could create one new migration file and loop through all of the tables that you want to add the fields to.

Comment: that's what i wrote on the post.I'm looking for other possible ways.

Comment: In your migration file you could define an array containing the names of the tables to apply the migration to and loop through the array.

Comment: @Peppermintology I'll try that.

Comment: Sorry, when I said loop through the tables, I meant create an array of the tables and loop through them. In your question, you mentioned going through all of the migrations (not tables).